# Jqgrid: hide cell based upon drop down in another cell

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using inline editing in a jqgrid. In one of my cells I have a drop down list. When an item is selected in this list I would like to hide or show a different cell on the same row. Please note I don't want to hide the entire column just the cell in the same row only. Is this possible?

Comment: It's very strange requirement. jqGrid uses HTML table to display the data. If one **hide** a cell (`<td>`) in the row the all other cells in the row will be displayed moved one cell on the left and the last column will be empty. In other words the cells after the hidden cell will be displayed in the wrong column. I can't imagine that it's what you want. I suppose that you formulated your requirement in the wrong way.

Comment: If the cell is editable this can be done, since the table cell contain input element. I need to ask if the cell that need to be hidden during editing is a editable cell of the same row? If this is the case it can be done. So just please let us know if this is the situation.